# Error on importing Wsdl as a connected service

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2015, wsdl, .net-core

I have an application that targets .NET Core.
When I try to import a wsdl file, I get the following error.

```
Scaffolding Code ...
Error:Error: Cannot import wsdl:portType
Detail: An exception was thrown while running a WSDL import extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: Schema with target namespace 'http://xml.amadeus.com/2010/06/Session_v3' could not be found.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://xml.amadeus.com']/wsdl:portType[@name='AmadeusWebServicesPT']
Warning: Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:portType that the wsdl:binding is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:portType: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://xml.amadeus.com']/wsdl:portType[@name='AmadeusWebServicesPT']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://xml.amadeus.com']/wsdl:binding[@name='AmadeusWebServicesBinding']
Warning: Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: 
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://xml.amadeus.com']/wsdl:service[@name='AmadeusWebServices']/wsdl:port[@name='AmadeusWebServicesPort']
Error: No endpoints compatible with .Net Core apps were found.
An error occurred in the tool.

Failed to generate service reference.
```

Is there any solution or workaround to that problem ?

Thanks.

**Edit:**

I have figured out the problem. To re-generate the stub, I need to run "svcutil.exe" directly from the command line (or generate the stub in some dummy C# project) because WCF Connected Services cannot generate a stub from this WSDL.

The generated code of the regarding wsdl uses following attributes that are not supported by .Net Standard 1.6.

> SerializableAttribute, DesignerCategoryAttribute

When I create these two attributes manually, then I am able to make my application build.

Comment: Where did you get the wsdl from?

Comment: I have downloaded it from the website of the provider/airline. (It is the wsdl of one of the biggest global distribution systems) I have tried to import this file by clicking on browse, it is not a basic endpoint url.

Comment: Can I see it? What tool did you use to consume it? svcutil.exe?

Comment: I am not using a tool, I have just opened a new Console Application (.NET Core) on VS 2015 and tried to import this wsdl as a connected service. Regardless of the wsdl file, I think it is the problem of .Net Core, but haven't figured it out, yet.

Comment: You cannot import the WSDL as a connected service because you're not connected to the service.

Comment: are you using Sabre GDS to connect to WSDL? How did you resolve the SerializableAttribute issue

Comment: @tomcamara I am using Amadeus GDS, not Sabre.

Comment: @ersegun But have you been able to connect to the webservice?

Comment: @miltoncamara yes, I have been able to connect to the web service as I explained. I haven't used Connected Service, I have just added it as Service Reference and copied the contents to my project.

Answer (score 2):

We can add services in 2 ways from `addservices` or from `dotnet-svcutil` tool.

The problem is that your web service endpoint's WSDL uses a different way of storing the XML operation data. As Henk points out, using the wrapped flag when manually running the `dotnet-svcutil` tool is the solution here.

Follow these steps:

1. Edit your .csproj file and add the following node inside the `<ItemGroup>` node: `<DotNetCliToolReference Include="dotnet-svcutil" Version="1.0.*" />`
2. Open up a PowerShell terminal from within the folder where the .csproj file resides.
3. Run `dotnet restore`
4. Run `dotnet svcutil https://smp.difi.no/ws/2.0?wsdl -wr`

Answer (score 1):

I was running into this issue as well. For me, the issue was there were a bunch of `*.xsd` files in the same directory as the WSDL file that I also had to reference. To fix it, I simply had to run the command like this:

```cs
dotnet-svcutil -wr .\WSDL\*.wsdl .\WSDL\*.xsd
```